# Un dropdown menu ocupa espacio como desplegado

Tags: css3, menú

Tengo este codigo css:

```
/*menu*/
.dropdownmenu ul, .dropdownmenu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; 
    left:5%;
    width:100%;

}
.dropdownmenu ul {
    background: gray;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
font-size: 18px;
}
.dropdownmenu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width:20%;
}
.dropdownmenu a {
    background: #30A6E6;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font: bold 12px/20px sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
.dropdownmenu li:hover a {
    background: #000000;
}
.submenu {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
position:absolute;

    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
li:hover ul.submenu {
    opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
.submenu li {

    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.submenu a:hover {
    background: #DF4B05;
}
.submenu a {
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

Y me muestra el menu con los submenu escondidos como debe ser, pero entre el menu y el resto del contenido queda un espacio blanco.

```
<p>
<h1>
CLIENTES</h1>

 </p>
        <label>Mostrar
            <select>

            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            </select>
            registros por pagina</label>
    <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="../../gestionweb/views/modules/nuevoCliente.php">Agregar</a>

<table>
<caption>Listado de clientes activos</caption>

<tr> <th>CUIT</th> <th>Nombre y Apellido</th> <th>Celular</th>
<th>Direccion</th> <th>Deuda Actual</th> <th>Accion</th>
</tr>
<?php 

$cliente=new Cliente();
$cliente::Listar();

foreach ($cliente as $C){?>
<tr>

            <td><?php echo $C->CUIT; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $C->nombre; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $C->celular; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $C->direccion; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $C->celular; ?></td>
            <td>
            <a  class="btn btn-warning" href="?c=cliente&a=Crud&id=<?php echo $r->id; ?>">Editar</a>
            <a  class="btn btn-danger" onclick="javascript:return confirm('¿Seguro de eliminar este registro?');" href="?c=cliente&a=Eliminar&id=<?php echo $r->id; ?>">Eliminar</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Podrías adjuntar el html en vez del php? Puedes hacerlo una vez renderizado con php `ctrl+u` en el navegador y copiar el código fuente.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head> <title>GESTION WEB</title> <meta charset="utf-8"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylos.css"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylos.css" />

</head>
<body>

<nav class="dropdownmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">ABM</a>
    <ul class="submenu" id="a">
        <li ><a href="index.php?controller=cliente&action=index">Clientes</a></li>
        <li ><a href="">Articulos</a></li>
        <li ><a href="">Proveedores</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Nuevo comprobante</a>
    <ul class="submenu"  id="b">
        <li ><a href="index.php?action=nuevoTicket">Ticket</a></li>
        <li ><a href="">Factura A</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Estado de cajas</a>
      <ul class="submenu" id="c">
        <li><a href="">Chequera</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Cerrar caja</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Posnet</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Busqueda Padron</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Compra de stock</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>



<table>
<caption>Ultimos Movimientos del Dia</caption>

<tr> <th>Fecha</th> <th>Hora</th> <th>Tipo Movimiento</th>
<th>Importe($)</th> <th>Subtotal($)</th>
</tr>
<tr> <td>Ar�ndano</td> <td>49</td> <td>0.2</td>
<td>0.4</td> <td>12.7</td>
</tr>
<tr> <td>Pl�tano</td> <td>90</td> <td>0.3</td>
<td>1.0</td> <td>23.5</td>
</tr>
<tr> <td>Cereza</td> <td>46</td> <td>0.4</td>
<td>0.9</td> <td>10.9</td>
</tr>
<tr> <td>Fresa</td> <td>37</td> <td>0.5</td>
<td>0.8</td> <td>8.3</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button"  class="botonimagenrefresh" value="      Actualizar"/>
<button class="botonimagenrefresh" value="Actualizar">    Actualizar </button>
 


</html>
```

y asi se ve:

[image: imagen con espacio blanco]

Answer (score -1):

No entiendo a que te refieres, ¿podrías subir una foto?
Aunque si es lo que yo pienso prueba a poner como regla CSS

```
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```